# TFS 2015 as nuget server

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, azure-devops, tfs-2015

We are currently testing whether we can replace our current build server (TeamCity) with TFS 2015 Build.

Does anyone know of TFS 2015 has built-in Nuget Server like TeamCity.

Thx

Answer (score 4):

[Package Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/what-is-packaging) (NuGet with npm and maven coming soon) is currently only available for VSTS. The on-premises support for Package Management will come in the next version of TFS.

Source - [TFS Feature Timeline for 2016](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

VSTS and TFS now provide built-in support for Maven Package Management to compliment its support of NuGet and npm.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/05/22/visual-studio-team-services-demonstrates-how-microsoft-loves-java/